# Cannot add UIBarButtonItem to toolbar in UINavigationController

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I have tried to add the `UIBarButtonItem` to the toolbar of `UINavigationController`, but it does not show any buttons and found that the `_toolbar` array is empty when I am doing debug.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        var default_title = ["A","B"," C","D"]
        var items: NSArray = NSArray()
        for title in default_title
        {
            items.arrayByAddingObject(UIBarButtonItem(title: title, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered, target: self, action: ""))
        }

        self.setToolbarItems(items as [AnyObject], animated: true)
        self.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: false)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the problem which is the `items` should be `Array<UIBarButtonItem>`.

code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    var default_title = ["A","B"," C","D"]
        var items: Array<UIBarButtonItem> = []
        for title in default_title
        {
            items.append(UIBarButtonItem(title: title, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered, target: self, action: ""))
        }

        self.setToolbarItems(items as [AnyObject], animated: true)
        self.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: false)
}
```